# Text rendering blurred in Firefox and Internet Explorer using jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, blur, jquery-animate

Not sure what causes this?

If I user slideDown in Firefox the text rendering cuts off the top of the letters before the animation is complete. This is ok in IE.

If I then change the animation to use fadeIn instead, the blur does not happen in Firefox but the text is very jagged in IE.

From another question I have asked in the past pertaining to animation, the guy told me that I should wrap that which I want to animate in another DIV and animate that instead. This sorted out the jerkiness caused by the padding on the content inside the .animateDiv.

Is there a trick to the text rendering as well in jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a technique [like here](http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457929/jquery-toggle-function-rendering-weird-text-in-ie-losing-cleartype).  Basically any fading in IE has to be done by a CSS filter, which is actually an IE specific thing that really FUBARs CelarType...so when you're finishing fading in or out, you need to remove that `filter` it leaves behind.

Now for partially faded text, this won't help, but if you're fading **all the way** in or out, this will clear up the result...during fading you'll still have jagged text, this is just how IE behaves unfortunately (IE9 fixes this, but IE7/8 aren't going anywhere for a long time).

If you use [the technique in the first link](http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/), just include the functions (just once) before using them anywhere, like this:

```
$.fn.customFadeIn = function(speed, callback) {
    $(this).fadeIn(speed, function() {
        if(!$.support.opacity)
            $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
        if(callback != undefined)
            callback();
    });
};
```

Then instead of `.fadeIn()`, you call `.customFadeIn()` instead, like this:

```
$("#uglyThingInIE").customFadeIn(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [IE has a problem with ClearType and animations](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/font-cleartype-problems-with-fadein-and.html). Not sure about FF.