# IE 7 result after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Text resolution becomes corrupted after jquery animation only on IE 7. Does anyone know the reason and how to avoid it.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide some code samples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery animate CSS opacity fade and @font-face gives Internet Explorer very ugly font rendering? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095872/using-jquery-animate-css-opacity-fade-and-font-face-gives-internet-explorer-very)

Comment: It's a commonly known problem. Solutions and more info: [here](http://old.nabble.com/Prevent-jagged-text-in-IE-td25620848s27240.html), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934460/text-rendering-blurred-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer-using-jquery), [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/fadetest.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095872/using-jquery-animate-css-opacity-fade-and-font-face-gives-internet-explorer-very) and a [test here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/fadetest.html).

Comment: @Andy thanks for the link, it contains the solution