# Remove filter attribute after jQuery UI dialog is finished opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, effects, jquery-ui-dialog

Using jQuery UI 1.8rc3 combined with the new `jquery.effects.fade.js` code, I've been able to finally apply fade-in and fade-out effects to opening the UI Dialog widgets.  Hooray!

```
$dialog.dialog({
        show: { effect: "fade", options: {}, speed: 150 }
}
```

This works great - unfortunately, [there's the known IE7 & 8 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411058/ie-is-losing-cleartype) where the ClearType gets turned off by the application of an empty `filter:` style attribute after the fade effect is finished.

I have the code to remove the filter attribute, I just can't find a good way to hook it into the event chain. The dialog's "open" and "focus" events are too soon.  I need something like a "dialog opening animation is finished" callback.

How can I hook up a callback to the end of the opening effect for a dialog?

Comment: `effect` itself takes a callback, e.g.: http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/#option-callback Have you tried putting it there?

Comment: I think that's the show() method that takes a callback.  If there is a way of specifying it in the options array (as I posted), I would love to be able to do that - but I don't seem to be able to find a good example.

Comment: the `show` object appears to take named properties for the arguments of the `show()` method.  Have you tried `show: { effect: "fade", options: {}, speed: 150, callback: function () { ... },` ?

Comment: Yeah I tried exactly that already - it didn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting your callback as the `complete` property of the "show" parameter object:

```
  .show({
    effect: "fade",
    options: {},
    speed: 150,
    complete: function() {
      /* interesting stuff to do here */
    }
  })
```

I got that by looking at the jQuery (core) source for `jQuery.speed` which is, I think, where that object passed to `show` will get sent.

Comment: Perfect!  I wish they'd update the documentation for this stuff ;)

Comment: I agree. I read all the time about how jQuery's documentation is so great, and while I am happy for what's available I **really** wish they'd make it a Wiki (or at least allow "editors" to register with minimal hassle).